# Sed: file or directory not found

Tags: linux, sed

I'm trying to use the sed command to replace text in a config file with the line

```
sed -e 's/pass/Awmusic12635/2w' -i config.yml
```

I have already cd to the directory to where the file is, but every time I run it I get the error

```
sed: couldn't open file : No such file or directory
```

What could be causing this?

OS: Ubuntu 10.10 32bit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your command to

```
$ sed -e 's/pass/Awmusic12635/2' -i config.yml
```

- it will change the second `pass` on every line to `Awmusic12635`
- if one line only contains single `pass`, it'll not be replaced
- if you want to change every `pass`, just change **`2`**(`second`) to **`g`**(`global`)
- **`w`** means `write`, but you didn't provide a file name after **`w`**, so you see the err msg.
- **`-i`** option means `edit-inplace`, so you don't need the **`w`**

Comment: so if I wanted to write the the file i would put 'sed -e 's/pass/Awmusic12635/2w config.yml' -i config.yml ?

Comment: Thanks that worked. And if I wanted to use a variable in one of the replacement parts would I need to use double quotes"" instead of '' ?

Comment: **`"s/pass/$MYVAR/g"`** will change all `pass` to `$MYVAR`(your variable)